# Why should I use "PaUtil_AllocateMemory" instead of malloc()?

Tags: c, memory-management, portaudio

I looked at [this example from the Portaudio page](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/paex__ocean__shore_8c_source.html) and wondered why the author uses

```
data.rBufToRTData = PaUtil_AllocateMemory(sizeof(OceanWave*) * 256);
```

instead of

```
data.rBufToRTData = malloc(sizeof(OceanWave*) * 256);
```

I could not find an answer to this on the Portaudio sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `PaUtil_AllocateMemory()`. It isn't part of the PortAudio public API. I have filed a [bug against the example](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/portaudio/tickets/226-paex_ocean_shore-uses-private-api--pautil_allocatememory#/activity/ticket%3a). Thanks for raising the issue.

That said, the example appears to be intended to demonstrate the use of some low-level internal data structures in PortAudio. In particular the PortAudio ring buffer. It should not be taken as a good example of using the PortAudio public API.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons the library could be using their own allocation function:

1. They could use memory pre-allocation or caching to improve performance.
2. It allows them to track references, making catching memory leaks easier.
3. If you use Portaudio as a DLL, it ensures that the structures are all allocated on the same heap.
4. To ensure that all memory allocations are aligned to a specific byte boundary.

Looking at the PortAudio source, it looks like they use their allocation method to track references if memory tracking is enabled, and to ensure the memory is all allocated on the same heap.

Either way, it is a best practice to use the library's allocation and free functions if they are provided.